# How to inherit and extend a list object in Python?

Tags: python, list, inheritance

I am interested in using the python list object, but with slightly altered functionality. In particular, I would like the list to be 1-indexed instead of 0-indexed. E.g.:

```
>> mylist = MyList()
>> mylist.extend([1,2,3,4,5])
>> print mylist[1]
```

output should be: 1

But when I changed the `__getitem__()` and `__setitem__()` methods to do this, I was getting a `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded` error. I tinkered around with these methods a lot but this is basically what I had in there:

```
class MyList(list):
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self[key-1]
    def __setitem__(self, key, item):
        self[key-1] = item
```

I guess the problem is that `self[key-1]` is itself calling the same method it's defining. If so, how do I make it use the `list()` method instead of the `MyList()` method? I tried using `super[key-1]` instead of `self[key-1]` but that resulted in the complaint `TypeError: 'type' object is unsubscriptable`

Any ideas? Also if you could point me at a good tutorial for this that'd be great!

Thanks!

Comment: This violates the Liskov Substitution Principle pretty blatantly.  There might not be a lot of value in subclassing `list` if you can't actually use it anywhere that a `list` would be expected.  Perhaps composition would be a more appropriate strategy in this case?

Comment: Don't quite understand; what do you mean by "composition"? Also, how can we be sure that we can't substitute MyList in place of a standard list? Is there a good way to tell? For example, if internal methods use `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` then would there be a problem?

Comment: mindthief: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance -- and if you change the existing interface of `list` (i.e., exactly what you're asking for here), then you can't substitute a `MyList` for a `list`.  Even basic things like `x[0]` won't work.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Use the `super()` function to call the method of the base class, or invoke the method directly:

```
class MyList(list):
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return list.__getitem__(self, key-1)
```

or

```
class MyList(list):
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return super(MyList, self).__getitem__(key-1)
```

However, this will not change the behavior of other list methods. For example, index remains unchanged, which can lead to unexpected results:

```
numbers = MyList()
numbers.append("one")
numbers.append("two")

print numbers.index('one')
>>> 1

print numbers[numbers.index('one')]
>>> 'two'
```

Comment: Also, beware of other list methods breaking because you're changing a behaviour of indexing which is a fundamental part of list objects.

Comment: I'll +1 if you note why the recursion occurs. You give the solution without explaining the problem.

Comment: Why the recursion occurs was explained perfectly well in the question.

Comment: One other gotcha to point out here: you'd think super(MyList, self)[key-1] would work, but it doesn't. super() explicitly doesn't work with any "implicit lookups" like [] instead of __getitem__.

Comment: "beware of other list methods breaking"
shouldn't those methods use `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` internally?

Comment: @mindthief: if they were using `__getitem__`, they could be accessing it as `self.__getitem__` which would invoke your implementation.

Answer (score 34):

Instead, subclass integer using the same method to define all numbers to be minus one from what you set them to.  Voila.

Sorry, I had to.  It's like the joke about Microsoft defining dark as the standard.

Comment: What's the joke about Microsoft defining dark as the standard? **Edit**: nvm, [found it](https://www.ocf.berkeley.edu/~mbarrien/jokes/lightblb.txt): *"Q: How many Microsoft hardware engineers does it take to change a light bulb? A: None, they redifine darkness as an industry standard"*

Answer (score 27):

You can avoid violating the [Liskov Substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) by creating a class that inherits from `collections.MutableSequence`, which is an abstract class. It would look something like this:

```
def indexing_decorator(func):
    def decorated(self, index, *args):
        if index == 0:
            raise IndexError('Indices start from 1')
        elif index > 0:
            index -= 1
        return func(self, index, *args)
    return decorated


class MyList(collections.MutableSequence):
    def __init__(self):
        self._inner_list = list()

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._inner_list)

    @indexing_decorator
    def __delitem__(self, index):
        self._inner_list.__delitem__(index)

    @indexing_decorator
    def insert(self, index, value):
        self._inner_list.insert(index, value)

    @indexing_decorator
    def __setitem__(self, index, value):
        self._inner_list.__setitem__(index, value)

    @indexing_decorator
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self._inner_list.__getitem__(index)

    def append(self, value):
        self.insert(len(self) + 1, value)
```

Comment: `x = MyList(); x.append(4); y = MyList(); print(y)`  Try it out.  You get interesting results...

Comment: Almost there. You should not adjust the index for `insert`. Also, try to handle case where index == 0.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But then the indexing would not be consistent. I edited the code in the answer a bit. It should work well now, I think.

Comment: Would it violate the Liskov substitution principle if one inherits from collections.UserList instead? e.g. class MyList(collections.UserList):

Comment: If you have something like `for x in thelist:` and the list contains 3 items, they you will get a call to `__getitem__(self, index)` where index is 4 and a list_index out of range error.  Perhaps someone can verify this and provide a fix?

Answer (score -8):

```
class ListExt(list):
    def extendX(self, l):
        if l:
            self.extend(l)
```