# Python: How can I inherit from the built-in list type?

Tags: python, list, inheritance, new-operator

I want to add some attributes to the built-in `list` type, so I wrote this:

```
class MyList(list):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        obj = super(MyList, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
        obj.append('FirstMen')
        return obj

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.name = 'Westeros'

    def king(self):
        print 'IronThrone'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_list = MyList([1, 2, 3, 4])
    print my_list
```

but `my_list` contains only the element `'FirstMen'`. Why my `__new__` doesn't work here? And how should I inherit from a built-in type like `list`? Is it the same for the immutable types like `str`?

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3945940/what-to-consider-before-subclassing-list) for some discussion on the subject of subclassing list, and how it's often not what you want.  (collections.MutableSequence, if available, might be a better route: read [Alex Martelli](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3488283/487339)).

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4093029/596361

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The `list` type usually does the actual initialisation of the list inside its `__init__()` method, as it is the convention for mutable types.  You only need to overwrite `__new__()` when subtyping immutable types.  While you *can* overwrite `__new__()` when subclassing list, there is not much point in doing so for your use case.  It's easier to just overwrite `__init__()`:

```
class MyList(list):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        list.__init__(self, *args)
        self.append('FirstMen')
        self.name = 'Westeros'
```

Also note that I recommend against using `super()` in this case.  You want to call `list.__init__()` here, and not possibly anything else.

Comment: Ah, I forgot to call the superclass's `__init__`. But how about the immutable types? Or is there a general rule about when `__new__` should be overridden?

Comment: @PJ.Hades: Only overwrite it if you need to.  This is generally the case if you need to influence the construction of the immutable data.  Subclassing `tuple` to add further methods and attributes does not require to overwrite `__new__()`.  If in doubt, just read the documentation.

Comment: @SvenMarnach, `self.append('FirstMen')` - where does `FirstMen` append - to `list` or `MyList` ?

Comment: Why would you use `list.__init__()` over `super().__init__()` ?

Comment: @ucb Generally, constructors of subclasses don't have necessarily the same prototype as the base class. `super()` may call the constructor of a random other class in a multiple inheritence scenario, which only works well when the constructors collaborate. It may not matter much, but I personally think using `super()` here just adds some unnecessary confusion. You know exactly what constructor you want to call, so it's best to be explicit about it.

Answer (score 11):

First of all, are you doing this as an exercise to understand `__new__`? If not, there is almost certainly a better way to do what you're trying to do. Could you explain what you'd like to achieve here?

That said, here's what's happening in your example:

1. You invoke `MyList([1,2,3,4])`
2. This first invokes `MyList.__new__(MyList,[1,2,3,4])`
3. Your implementation calls `list.__new__(MyList,[1,2,3,4])`
   This returns a new instance of `MyList`, with no elements. `list.__new__` does not populate the list. It leaves that to `list.__init__`, which is never called.
4. Your `__new__` method appends `'FirstMen'` to the empty `MyList` instance.
5. Your `__new__` method returns the instance of `MyList`.
6. `MyList.__init__([1,2,3,4])` is invoked.
7. It sets the `name` attribute to `'Westeros'`.
8. It returns.
9. The instance is assigned to `my_list` and printed.

See here for an explanation of `__new__`: http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#basic-customization

Comment: I knew the cause of this problem. Thanks for your explanation :)

Comment: Note that if `MyList.__init__()` *did* call `list.__init__()`, it would replace the content of the list by `[1, 2, 3, 4]`, so the `'FirstMen'` would be gone.