# How to define the schema to make a list not allow empty?

Tags: python, eve

In the [python-eve REST API framework](http://python-eve.org) I define a list in a resource, the type of the list item is dict. And I don't want the list to be empty. So, how to define the schema?

```
{
    'parents' : {
        'type' : 'list',
        'schema' : {
            'parent' : 'string'
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently the `empty` validation rule is only available for string types, but you can subclass the standard validator to make it capable of processing lists:

```
from eve.io.mongo import Validator

class MyValidator(Validator):
    def _validate_empty(self, empty, field, value):
        # let the standard validation happen
        super(Validator, self)._validate_empty(empty, field, value)
        # add your custom list validation
        if isinstance(value, list) and len(value) == 0 and not empty:
            self._error(field, "list cannot be empty")
```

or, if want to provide the standard `empty` error message instead:

```
from eve.io.mongo import Validator
from cerberus import errors

class MyValidator(Validator):
    def _validate_empty(self, empty, field, value):
        # let the standard validation happen
        super(Validator, self)._validate_empty(empty, field, value)
        # add your custom list validation
        if isinstance(value, list) and len(value) == 0 and not empty:
            self._error(field, errors.ERROR_EMPTY_NOT_ALLOWED)
```

Then you run your API like this:

```
app = Eve(validator=MyValidator)
app.run()
```

PS: I plan on adding lists and dicts to Cerberus' `empty` rule sometime in the future.

Answer (score -1):

There isn't an inbuilt way to do this. You could define a wrapper class for your list though:

```
class ListWrapper(list):
    # Constructor
    __init__(self, **kwargs):
        allIsGood = False
        # 'kwargs' is a dict with all your 'argument=value' pairs
        # Check if all arguments are given & set allIsGood
        if not allIsGood:
            raise ValueError("ListWrapper doesn't match schema!")
        else:
            # Call the list's constructor, i.e. the super constructor
            super(ListWrapper, self).__init__()

            # Manipulate 'self' as you please
```

Use `ListWrapper` wherever you need your non-empty list. You could externalize the definition of the schema somehow if you'd like and add it as an input to the constructor.

*Also:* You might want to take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4093029/how-to-inherit-and-extend-a-list-object-in-python)

Comment: Do you mean to define a Custom Validation Rules like http://python-eve.org/validation.html#custom-validation-rules

Comment: No I didn't because I didn't want to use external packages. You can add a `Validator` to validate your fields if you're using eve.