# What is dict.get(self, key) in a class extending python Dict

Tags: python, dictionary

Came across code where a class which extends Dict class and overrides the methods.

Following code snippet is what I can't understand:

```
class HeaderKeyDict(dict):
"""
A dict that title-cases all keys on the way in, so as to be
case-insensitive.
"""
    # More methods

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return dict.get(self, key.title())

    def get(self, key, default=None):
        return dict.get(self, key.title(), default)

   # More methods
```

What is confusing me is what is dict.get(self, ...) doing ? Is this similar to dict.get(key) method ?

Will dict.get(self) call the self.get() method when we do [ ] on this class object ?

Comment: it simply overwrites the `.get` method for this particular flavour of `dict`s (inherits from `dict`). The only difference is the default value (`key.title()`)

Comment: @Ev.Kounis The default value is still `None`. The difference is the key will get capitalized.

Comment: Title case is a weird way to make the key case-insensitive.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Oh I see now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case `dict.get(self, key.title())` is equivalent to `super().get(key.title())`. It is calling the "original" `.get` method of the `dict` class but forcing the `key` to be "titlized".

To understand why `dict.get(self, key.title())` is equivalent to `super().get(key.title())` let's have a look at a simpler class:

```
class Foo:
    def bar(self):
        print('bar')
```

Now, calling `Foo().bar()` is the same as calling `Foo.bar(Foo())`. This is essentially the same as what is going on in your case without the inheritance.

Comment: Thanks. Right after I posted this question, found a similar Q/A for list https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4093029/how-to-inherit-and-extend-a-list-object-in-python

Comment: I had never seen such a invocation before `dict.get(self)`, and that is what got me confused